# My php code with python is not working in XAMPP

Tags: php, python, xampp

I have a Python code in Anaconda (Jupyter). This is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print (sys.argv[1])
```

I would like to connect with this code using PHP. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
echo shell_exec("python xxxx.py 'hello'");          
?>
```

I am running my PHP code using XAMPP. So, my PHP file is in my local machine in htdocs.

The expected result is to print “hello”. However, I am not getting anything when I run my PHP code. I tried to have my Python code in htdocs as well, but I am not getting any result neither. please help we are stuck.

Comment: All those   around your codeblock, I assume that's because you pasted the question, and that they aren't actually there in your code?

Comment: What have you done for debugging so far? What does your `shell_exec()` return?

Comment: @Qirel for debugging, when we remove the line where we are importing the pandas everything works perfectly, and hello is printed. as soon as we import pandas in python it does not work.  shell_exec() passes hello as a parameter to the file xxxx.py

Comment: So by that logic, you are having issues importing the `pandas` package. Is it installed? What does your console tell you when you attempt to run this python script on its own?